# getting facebook share count using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, facebook, jquery

I wrote the following code:

```
function shareCount(url){
    var count;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+share_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2F9gag.com%2Fgag%2F"+encodeURIComponent(url)+"%22",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
                alert($(xml).find('share_count').text());
                return $(xml).find('share_count').text();
        }
    });
    //alert(count);
}
```

it simply sends a fql query to facebook to get `share_count` for a given link, the link is fine, and `alert($(xml).find('share_count').text());` works but when I return the count the other function says the var is undefined! same thing happens when I uncomment the `alert()` at the end scope.

here is part of the other function that sends a request to this function (not sure if its relevant)

```
g.innerHTML = h("#template", {
                id: c.images[a].id,
                title: c.images[a].title,
                image: c.images[a].image.small,
                time: c.images[a].time,
                votes: c.images[a].votes,
                url: c.images[a].url,
                shareCount: shareCount(c.images[a].id)
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

The alert executes before ajax completes.

Why use your own ajax methods to get fb data ?
Why don't you use [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), something like below should do it

```
FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT share_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = "http://9gag.com/gag/"'
}, function (data) {
    alert(data[0].share_count);
    //    do the rest here
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/kR8Hp/3/)

Hope this helps